# GAE Go size of datastore

Tags: database, google-app-engine, go

Is there some function one can call to get the amount of entries in the GAE Go Datastore of an app, without querying it for the whole database and counting the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)
    var result struct {
        Bytes int64 `datastore:"bytes"`
        Count int64 `datastore:"count"`
        Timestamp datastore.Time `datastore:"timestamp"`
    }
    datastore.NewQuery("__Stat_Total__").Run(c).Next(&result)
    c.Infof("count: %d", result.Count)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can view the size of all entities in the admin console under Data > Datastore Statistics.

These stats can be queried programmatically from [Python](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/stats.html) or [Java](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/stats.html); I couldn't find a documented equivalent for Go.

Comment: The Python and Java libraries for this are just wrappers around the datastore entities; you can access them directly in any language.